# non-serializable values were found in the navigation state when passing a function in params Warn

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

During development with react-native + expo + typescript

Pass function from Screen A to Screen B as Params.

Make your selections on Screen B.
Selected items are stored in the state using useState.

When clicking the "Complete" button, navigation.pop() is executed and the function received as Params from Screen A is executed.

There is no problem with the operation, but it is sending this warning.

Is there any better way?

```
Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state. Check:

ScreenB > params.callback (Function)

This can break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might happen if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class instances etc. in params. If you need to use components with callbacks in your options, you can use 'navigation.setOptions' instead. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state for more details.
```